# Неверное отображение DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

App.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    BoardVM boardVM = new BoardVM();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = boardVM }.Show();
    }
}
```

BoardVM.cs:

```
class BoardVM : VM
{
    public BoardVM()
    {
        gridLoad();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyTable> data;

    public ObservableCollection<MyTable> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    void gridLoad()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<MyTable>(
           File.ReadLines(path,
               System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
           .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
           .Select(x => new MyTable
           {
               ...
           }));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

В конструкторе класса BoardVM я заполняю ObservableCollection данными,которые биндятся к DataGrid, но почему-то в DataGrid в конце таблицы появляется пустая строка. Как это исправить?

Comment: Draktharon, получилось у вас?

Comment: @Андрей да, спасибо, забыл отметить ваш ответ как верный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите значение свойства [`CanUserAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) в `false`.

При значении `true` (по умолчанию) `DataGrid` отображает снизу пустую строку в которую можно добавить новый элемент